# React native navigation useTheme()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-stylesheet

I'm trying to access useTheme() directly from the styles
But so far my solution doesn't seem to work.
I'm not getting in error back.
Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

```
 import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

    import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
    
    export default function () {
            const { colors } = useTheme();
            const styles = GlobalStyles({ colors: colors })
            return styles
        }
        
        const GlobalStyles = (props) => StyleSheet.create({
        
            container: {
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: props.colors.backgroundColor,
        
            },
        })
```

Accessing style in component

```
 import React from "react";
import GlobalStyles from "../globalStyles.js"
    
    class Inventory extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
    
            return (
                <View style={globalStyles.container}>
            )
    
     }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a couple of issues: you can only use a hook within a hook or a function component. So you could convert your global stylesheet into a hook:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
    
const getGlobalStyles = (props) => StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: props.colors.backgroundColor,
  },
});

function useGlobalStyles() {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  // We only want to recompute the stylesheet on changes in color.
  const styles = React.useMemo(() => getGlobalStyles({ colors }), [colors]);

  return styles;
}

export default useGlobalStyles;
```

Then you can use the hook by converting your `Inventory` class component into a function component and using the new `useGlobalStyles` hook.

```
import React from "react";
import useGlobalStyles from "../globalStyles.js"
    
const Inventory = () => {
  const globalStyles = useGlobalStyles();

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!