# How do I use the useTheme hook inside my Stylesheet create?

Tags: react-native, themes, react-native-paper

I want to use the colors from my react native paper theme inside the stylesheet create function inside my component. Here's my code

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';

const Home = () => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: colors.background }]}>
      <Text>Home Page</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


export default Home;
```

I want to have the backgroundColor: "#fff" in the stylesheet to reference the colors.background coming from the useTheme hook. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use your StyleSheet inside your Home function/component

Answer (score 28):

I prefer to use it like this

```
const makeStyles = (colors: any) => StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
       backgroundColor: colors.red,
   }
})
```

then, in render()

```
  const Home = () => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();
  const styles = makeStyles(colors)
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: colors.background }]}>
      <Text>Home Page</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This will unncessarily create a new StyleSheet on each rerender. To avoid that, add change the styles line to: const styles = useMemo(() => makeStyles(colors), [colors]);

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259425/8142053

I found this answer very recently from StackOverflow, according to that you can write a customHook and use it inside the custom hook. Please view his answer for a clear understanding.